# Finding minimum cost in 2D matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

In my last interview, I was asked a question for which optimal approach I am still not able to figure out.

Given a 2D matrix, with `n rows` and `m columns`, I need to select one item from each row and get the minimum sum.

But the tricky part was, while going down, I have two options:

1. choose the element in same column as prev one.
2. Choose element apart from the current column

So, the 2nd option, i.e changing column while going down can be done exactly `K` times. We can revisit the same column down the matrix. Change is defined only when we change the column between current and next row.

What I tried in front of the interviewer was something like `Painting wall problem`, where given 3 types of paints I need to find minimum cost so that no two adjacant walls are painted the same color. But there the  m value was fixed to 3, and I can use simple `cost[i][j] = min(cost[i-1][j-1], cost[i-1][j+1]);` //min of the other two rows from the current one.

So problem as above, what should be the approach, it does feel like DP to me but I am really not sure if it gives result.

Comment: @SomeDude What I meant was, while going down the matrix I have two options : choose the element in the same row or choose any other element. So choosing any element apart from my current column is changing the column. 
So, this changing of column while going down can happen only K times.

Comment: *can be done exactly K times* means you "have to" change `K` times right? not upto K times? also the next column you choose need not be adjacent column? and what about revisting the column you already visited? all these are possible I presume?

Comment: @SomeDude we need to change the column exactly `K` times, and we can revisit the same column later down the path.
Change will be defined only from the current and next column.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using dynamic programming: let `dp[i][j][l]` be the minimum sum we can get by choosing some numbers from the first `i` rows, the last one being in `j` th column, and having made exactly `l` column changes. Initially `dp[0][j][0] = matrix[0][j]`. For the updates we should the following formula:

If we go with the first option, let's do this:
`dp[i + 1][j][l] = min(dp[i + 1][j][l], dp[i][j][l] + matrix[i + 1][j])`.

If we go with the second option, we should do this for all `new_col != j`:
`dp[i + 1][new_col][l + 1] = min(dp[i + 1][new_col][l + 1], dp[i][j][l] + matrix[i + 1][new_col])`

The result will be the minimum value among `dp[n - 1][j][k]` for all `j`. Overall complexity is
`O(n * m^2 * k)` because for all states of the dynamic (`O(n * m * k)`) we do updates in `O(m)` time while iterating over `new_col` for the second type and `O(1)` for the first type.

We can do better than this. Let's find the smallest `dp[i][j][l]` for fixed `i`, `l`, iterating over all possible `j`. Suppose it's in column number `min_j`, and the value is `x`. For all `j != min_j` `x` will be used for updates of the second type in row `i + 1`.

The only column which is updated using a different value is `min_j` itself, because if we went from
`dp[i][min_j][l]` to `dp[i + 1][min_j][l + 1]`, we wouldn't switch the column. Let's calculate
`dp[i + 1][min_j][l + 1]` by iterating over all `j != min_j` as we used to do before. Total number of operations is `O(m)`.

The complexity will be `O(n * m * k)` because we are doing `O(m)` updates for all different pairs `i, l` and there's `O(n * k)` of them.

Comment: That is indeed a beautiful solution, especially the optimisation part.
The sentence, `Suppose it's in row number min_j, and the value is x`, in the optimisation part, what you meant is column and not row number right?

Comment: @torrtuga Thanks! That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Won't this fail when `k=0` as it will take the first row min value, and without switching columns just keeps calculating downwards.

Comment: @torrtuga We're not changing the way we do updates of the first type because they're done in `O(1)` per state anyways. Our answer in case `k = 0` will consist of updates of the first type only, e.g. we're not allowed to switch columns. In `dp[n - 1][j][0]` will be the sum of numbers in the `j` th row.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using top down approach.

You start at a location on the first row and to traverse down from there. You have two options:

a) Continue on the same column - but you need to take into consideration that you have enough rows for `K` switches. So your condition should be `remaining_rows >= K` then you can take this option otherwise not.

b) Switch your column to any other column. Consider all columns.

Out of those two options take the minimum.

The recursive equation will be then:

```
getMin(r, c, K) = min( 
                   (R - (r+1) >= K ? getMin(r+1, c, K) + A[r][c] : A[r][c] ),
                   ( for all j != c, j < C: min(getMin(r+1, c, K-1)) )
                  )
```

where `A` is the input matrix and `R` is the number of rows and `C` is the number of columns in `A`.

and you take the minimum of `getMin(0, c, K )` for all `c = 0` to `C`

You can memoize the solution for each `r, c, K`.

For `K = 0` , just traverse down the column and get the sum.

Code in Java is :

```
class Main {
    private static int[][][] dp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] A = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 4, 3, 1 }, { 6, -2, 5 }, { 1, 4, -3 } };

        int K = 3;
        dp = new int[A.length][A[0].length][K + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < A[0].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 1; k <= K; k++) {
                    dp[i][j][k] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }
            }
        }
        int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = 0; j < A[0].length; j++)
            res = Math.min(res, getMin(A, 0, j, K));
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    private static int getMin(int[][] A, int r, int c, int K) {
        int R = A.length, C = A[0].length;
        if (r > R - 1 || c > C - 1)
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (K == 0) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = r; i < R; i++)
                sum += A[i][c];
            return sum;
        }
        if (dp[r][c][K] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            return dp[r][c][K];
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int rem_rows = R - (r + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (j == c && rem_rows >= K) {
                int s = getMin(A, r + 1, j, K);
                if (s != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    min = Math.min(min, s + A[r][c]);
                } else {
                    min = Math.min(min, A[r][c]);
                }

            } else if (j != c) {
                int m = getMin(A, r + 1, j, K - 1);
                if (m != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    min = Math.min(min, m + A[r][c]);
                } else {
                    min = Math.min(min, A[r][c]);
                }
            }
        }
        dp[r][c][K] = min;
        return min;
    }
}
```

You can play with the [live code here](https://repl.it/repls/SphericalWanDecagon)